# how to restrict number of instances of a class in C++ or JAVA?

Tags: java, c++, class, object, instance

The question was asked to me in an interview, i tried to think could not answer it, i want a piece of Code either in C++ or JAVA that restricts number of instance ( objects ) of a class.

Comment: `class Nope { Nope() = delete; };` limits the class to zero instances ;)

Comment: Use a builder that holds the amount of instances created. That doesn't take reflection into account though.

Comment: The question is pointless, unless having a threading context and limiting the number of worker threads. +1 Daniel Frey

Answer (score 10):

Use a factory. Keep a private static counter of the number of instances released. Don't allow the constructor for your instance-limited class to be visible.

Comment: @khajvah A factory is a method which is used to create objects, just like  factory is real life ;)

Comment: That's something you should google for. There are plenty of examples out there. google: "java factory design pattern" and "java factory method".

Answer (score 6):

Try like this using a `static variable` in **C++**:-

```
struct myclass
{
  myclass()
  {
    if(count == N) { /*throw some exception here!*/ }
    ++count;
  }
  ~myclass()
  {
    --count;
  }
private:
  static std::size_t count = 0;
};
```

Whenever a object is created then the count variable is incremented by 1.

**In JAVA**

A sample implementation could be like this:-

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final int LIMIT = 10; //Set this to whatever you want to restrict
    private static int count = 0;
    private MyClass() {}
    public static synchronized MyClass getInstance() {
        if (count < LIMIT) {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            count++;
            return myClass;
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this prevent anything? (Never mind multi-threading...)

Comment: @DanielFrey:- I was just trying to to make a point that we can detect that how many objects are created and then may be try to restrict that. Do correct me if I am wrong!! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi At least make it `if( count == N ) throw "limit reached";` or something that answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can restrict instances of class upto some specific limit. It is just an enhancement to [Singleton Design Pattern](http://codepumpkin.com/?p=398)

By making our constructor private and then creating a visible constructor method, we can limit the number of instance creations (like we do in singleton design pattern) or recycle instances or other construction-related tasks.

Doing new x() never returns null, but using the factory pattern, you can return null.

Here is the Java implementation for the same :

```
public class LimitObjectCreationTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        LimitClass obj;
        int i=1;
        while(i<=20)
        {
            obj = LimitClass.getLimInstance();
            i++;
        }
      }
}


class LimitClass {

    /**
     * count of alive instances in JVM  
     */
    public static int objCount = 0;

    /**
     * private constructor
     * increases the objCount static variable on every object creation
     */
    private LimitClass(){
        objCount++;
        System.out.println("instance " + objCount + " created");
    }

    /**
     * static factory method to return LimitClass instance
     * @return instance of LimitClass if not reached to threshold, else returns null
     */
    public static synchronized LimitClass getLimInstance() {
        if(objCount < 3 ){
            return new LimitClass();
        }
        System.out.println("Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object");
        System.gc();
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * decreases the objCount static variable when JVM runs garbage collection
     * and destroys unused instances
     */
    @Override
    public void finalize()
    {
        System.out.println("Instance destroyed");
         objCount--;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
instance 1 created
instance 2 created
instance 3 created
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance destroyed
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance destroyed
instance 3 created
Instance destroyed
instance 2 created
instance 3 created
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance destroyed
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance destroyed
instance 3 created
Instance destroyed
instance 3 created
instance 3 created
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance destroyed
Instance Limit reached. Can not create new Object
Instance destroyed
Instance destroyed
instance 1 created
instance 2 created
```

output may vary based on your allocated JVM memory.

**Reference :** http://codepumpkin.com/use-private-constructor-java/

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is **By using Factory Methods** and if question was how to do this?...**By making constructor Private**
A very simple example is:

```
class SingletonClass{ //i.e class with only one instance
private int a;
private SingletonClass() // here you see constructor is private
{}
private static SingletonClass ref; // this is static reference of the class
public static SingletonClass getInstance(){ //this is the factory method
if(ref==null)
ref=new SingletonClass();
return ref;
}
public void setA(int a){
this.a = a;
}
public int getA(){
return a;
}
}
class Demo{
public static void main(String []s){
SingletonClass s,p; // 2 references for the SingletonClass
s = new SingletonClass(); /*this will generate compile time error since contructor is                        private */
s = SingletonClass.getInstance();
p = SingletonClass.getInstance();
s.setA(10);
p.setA(20);
System.out.println(s.getA()+" "+p.getA());
}
}
```

Here the output will be **20 20** since both reference are pointing the same object.

Actually object is not made **unless contructor is called**(thats why its called as constructor) and if we make the contructor private then we can restrict the creation of object and then with factory methods we can control the creation as we want as in this case it only allows creation of 1 object.
It will call the contructor only if no objects are created for the class and after that it will just send the reference.
**Hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution

```
class XYZ {
private statuc XYZ[] instance;
public XYZ[] getInstance(){

if (instance == null) {

instance = new XYZ[4] ; // here I am restricted to make only 4 inxtance

}// if ends here
return instance;

}// getinstance() ends here

}// class ends here
```

With this function we can add other methods and variables as per requirement